# Accessing WRT54G admin through WET610N bridge

Tags: cisco, router, bridge, wifi, wireless-bridge

I am using a WRT54G router to host a few computers and servers. I have another computer that is wired to a wireless bridge, which is a WET610N.

How do I access the admin page of my WRT54G through my bridge? "http://192.168.1.1/" gives no response.

What I really want is to be able to RDC into my other machines that are connected to my WRT54G through my computer that is connected to the WET610N bridge.

[image: diagram 1]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your wireless APs cannot communicate with each other right now; the linksys devices should be configured to participate in a [Wireless Distribution System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_LAN#Wireless_distribution_system) with the same WPA keys and wifi channel.

I am not sure whether the stock linksys firmware supports this mode; several open-source firmware packages support WDS.